# import only data to mysql database from sql file

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to import only data from a sql file. This file contains create tables, alter and etc. I need to import it from the Linux command line. I tried this:

```
--no-create-info test < /mydb.sql
```

I'm trying this but not getting data only. I don't get erros.
I'm trying this command but it restores the data and the structure tables.

```
mysql -u 'root' -p  test < /mydb.sql
```

I only need to restore the data and not the structure. Please give me your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are missing some basic things. First, `--no-create-info` option applies to *exporting* operations, when you wish to get your data from database to a file. In this case, the `create alter` etc. commands are not put to the result file.

Instead, when *importing* data to a table, you must first create it. MySQL won't do it for you. And `--no-create-info` does not make sense in this case.

If you wish to import data to an existing table, and you do not want it to be recreated or altered, you can edit your file before importing. Just remove the lines where your tables are created/altered. But in this case the structure of the target table must fit the structure of the data you import. MySQL will not adjust the data table for you.